# Retrieve string with matching pattern and stuff with hyphen sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following four strings.

```
ABC!View1=DA7932BA-9BDC-40AC-99B9-2C066D1533A3;3|
ABC!Download=DA7932BA-9BDC-40AC-99B9-2C066D1533A3;3|FindMe=46739721;6|
PQR!View1=F1864EB3-B9F5-4289-8C58-1581830486A8;3|
PQR!Download=F1864EB3-B9F5-4289-8C58-1581830486A8;3|FindMe=47315901;6|
```

as output I need single row for which I am stuffing all four results into one row which gives me results as below.

```
ABC!View1=DA7932BA-9BDC-40AC-99B9-2C066D1533A3;3|ABC!Download=DA7932BA-9BDC-40AC-99B9-2C066D1533A3;3|FindMe=46739721;6|PQR!View1=F1864EB3-B9F5-4289-8C58-1581830486A8;3|PQR!Download=F1864EB3-B9F5-4289-8C58-1581830486A8;3|FindMe=47315901;6|
```

However for one repeating particular parameter I need output like following.

```
ABC!View1=DA7932BA-9BDC-40AC-99B9-2C066D1533A3;3|ABC!Download=DA7932BA-9BDC-40AC-99B9-2C066D1533A3;3|PQR!View1=F1864EB3-B9F5-4289-8C58-1581830486A8;3|PQR!Download=F1864EB3-B9F5-4289-8C58-1581830486A8;3|*FindMe=46739721-47315901*;6|
```

With SubString I can get one string between pattern like "FindMe=" and ";6" but I cannot stuff them into one variable. can someone help me here?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and string functions are highly vendor specific . Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: _but I cannot stuff them into one variable_: I don't understand what this means.  Please can you show what you have already done and highlight where it fails to meet your expectation?

Comment: I am using SQL server.